# How do I declare a function that accepts anything that can be turned into HashMap<String,String>

Tags: function, hashmap, rust

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Fields {
    map: HashMap<String, String>
}
```

For ergonomics, I want a function that accepts both `&str` and `String`. I read that `HashMap` has a trait `FromIterator<(K, V)>`, so at an abstract level I could work from *anything* that produces an iterator of pairs that turns into strings.

Analogously, if I want a function that accepts anything that can be turned into a `String`, I can use the bound `T: Into<String>`.

Can the same be done for an iterator of pairs that can be turned into strings? Conceptually:

```
fn set_map<I: IntoIterator<Item=(Into<String>, Into<String>)>>(fields: I) {
    // ...
}
```

This errors with

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::convert::Into<std::string::String> + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | / fn set_map<I: IntoIterator<Item = (Into<String>, Into<String>)>>(fields: I) {
2 | |     // ...
3 | | }
  | |_^ `std::convert::Into<std::string::String> + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::convert::Into<std::string::String> + 'static`
  = note: only the last element of a tuple may have a dynamically sized type

error[E0038]: the trait `std::convert::Into` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | fn set_map<I: IntoIterator<Item = (Into<String>, Into<String>)>>(fields: I) {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::Into` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `Item`'s tuple elements as types (as opposed to traits). The following should work:

```
fn set_map<S: Into<String>, T: Into<String>, I: IntoIterator<Item=(S, T)>>(fields: I) {
    ...
}
```

Two different parameters `S` and `T` instead of just one allow you to have different `Into<String>` types in the tuple.

Comment: I would use two separate parameters for the tuple elements. Doesn't matter if the two elements have the same type, as long as they can both be turned into strings.

Comment: Magical! Thanks!